# Flow server are running but vscode-flow-ide don't display errors on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I'm lost, I installed vscode-flow-ide to be able to see my errors in my IDE but, although the flow server runs, no errors are displayed. If I run `flow check`, it returns lots of errors. but on the IDE I didn't see anything.

I know he must have something display on the bottom left like `Flow coverage : x%`

I know the config is good because the others people who work on the project, don't have any problem. But no one are on Windows. Someone have the same issue with a windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite struggling with it as well.

Is there a flow path set up in VS Code project (Preference -> Settings -> search for "flow") or in a .vscode/settings.json file ?

If so it is most likely not the same as your coworkers on Mac ( even "/" instead or "\" probably messes it up).

You can either delete any path config and let vscode figure it out, or precise your own path to flow. It will be different if you did a local or global install.

You could try "where flow" in command prompt to see the absolute path to your flow installation.